# Clang linking problems

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to run clang(clang-tidy) on my cpp files. And I get errors like:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
```

I searched problem in the Internet, but couldn't find solution. I used [this guide](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) to download llvm and clang. I tried to link my headers with `-DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `-stdlib` option but it didn't work.

Ubuntu system.

```
$ clang -v 
clang version 9.0.0-2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Comment: You don't need to download it from the internet. It's for experienced developers. Use the package manager of your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. check weather you are working in the directory that has the .c++ file
   ** by clang I understand you are trying to run the program from a command line whether Mac linux or windows**
2. I'm  a Mac user so what I do to run clang is:

   a. gcc -std=c++11 -c file.cpp or gcc -std=gnu++11 -c file.cpp

   b. gcc -c file.cpp 
   but method (a) is better because method (b) uses clang version that was installed on the machine from the factory but with method (a) you can specify c++11 or even 
   c++17

Comment: 1) yes I'm working in the correct dicrectory 2) adding standard option doesn't help me at all, it doesn't do anything